# Polinomial regression with Mean Absolute Error cost function Python

Tags: python, function, regression, gradient, loss

Is there any polynomial or linear regression function in python,  which error function is the Mean Absolute Error? Sklearn use MSE, but since the noise in the data has normal distribution, i would like to use MAE to minimise.
After that i need a mathematical function(coefficients) also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392783/training-linear-models-with-mae-using-sklearn-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this part of the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html), sklearn can use Mean Absolute Error.
As shown in the example on their page:

```py
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
>>> y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
>>> y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
0.5
>>> y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
>>> y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
0.75
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='raw_values')
array([0.5, 1. ])
>>> mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred, multioutput=[0.3, 0.7])
0.85...
```

**Update:**
as pointed in a comment, this is a prediction method. For regression check out [this site](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-custom-scikit-learn-regression-5d0d718f289), describing writing own Regressor with MAE function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code only shows the MAE for the prediction. I'm searching for the regression method, where the loss function is the MAE.

Comment: @Máté Tóth [this site](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-custom-scikit-learn-regression-5d0d718f289) describes a process of writing your own regressor with MAE regression method.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

light gbm regression can work with MAE